# Is it possible to mix classical database with one view column?

Tags: mysql, view

I would like to create a database, which is editable, but one of the columns is a VIEW of another database. Is it possible to mix them?

I tried with FOREIGN KEY, but this gives me only a reference not an explicit value

Comment: *"I tried with FOREIGN KEY, but this gives me only a reference not an explicit value"* Not sure what you are doing here or want to do here, add a usercase... See [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: MYSQL does support generated columns https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-generated-columns.html if that's what you mean but I suspect a VIEW in a generated column would not be.